matplotlib ImportError: DLL load fail in VSCode
While setting up a new machine to be able to develop python files in Visual Studio Code, I ran into an import error for the matplotlib library:
File "C:\Users\lab_L\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.

(Full Traceback included below)
I am using a .venv virtual environment, created with the 'Python: Create Environment' command from the VS Code command palate. It appears to be using the proper environment when I run my code since it is able to find the other modules (numpy and pandas) without issue. It appears I somehow am installing the matplotlib library incorrectly or perhaps it is a dependency issue.
I am happy to hear any suggestions or offer any other info that may help in answering this issue.
Here is the code I am running and the full traceback:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_x = np.arange(10)
test_y = np.arange(10)

plt.plot(test_x,test_y)

PS C:\Users\lab_L\Projects> & c:/Users/lab_L/Projects/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/lab_L/Projects/Scrap/plot_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lab_L\Projects\Scrap\plot_test.py", line 3, in <module>    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\lab_L\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\lab_L\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lab_L\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.

I have tried:

setting up the virtual environment from the command line in a VS Code terminal (cmd)
creating an venv environment in the command line outside vscode and running from there
verifying I have only 1 version of matplotlib installed in the environment
verifying that I am able to use other libraries in the environment
uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib and kiwisolver
uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code

Since I am setting the computer up for the first time I went ahead and even completely reset the computer to factory settings, removing all settings and files.
I then did the same set up process I have used to set up 4 previous machines, only to have this one fail again.

The error is occurring because the Python interpreter is unable to load a DLL that's required by kiwisolver. Can you try to reinstall kiwisolver by command pip uninstall kiwisolver and pip install kiwisolver.

Just tried it, unfortunately still seeing the same error. I can post the traceback again if it would help but it is the same as the error before

Can this answer help? Try to install https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

That fixed the issue thank you, I was struggling to find out if I had the proper DLL file.
